# local storage in browser not incrementing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I'm trying to build a date booking feature that returns the total cost of a booking based on the dates selected and the cost associated with that booking.

I have converted the dates into milliseconds and I'm looping through the possible date ranges that costs are assigned to (15th dec - 15th jan = 220 dollars per night for example).

I then want to store in local storage the count of times that a date falls within a particular date range so I can just do the math at the end of multiplying the number of times dates fall within a date range and multiple by that cost.

My issue is i'm not sure if I am correctly incrementing the count in the local storage as shown in the screenshot below

```
for (let i = 0; i < daysDifference; i++) {  //for loop to go through each day
    let dayDot = startTime + (i * 86400000); // getting the range for each day of the booking in millisecs
    localStorage.setItem("dayscost0", "0") //setting day count in each range to zero in local storage
    if (dayDot <= 1639746000000 && dayDot >= 1634648400000) { // setting range for price blocks
      let cost = (parseInt(localStorage.getItem('dayscost0')) + 1); //incrementing by one each time a value fits the range
      localStorage.setItem("dayscost0", cost.toString()) //adding the value to local storage
      console.log('dayscost0') 
    }
```

[browser Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OWaA.png)

Comment: Why would you do that in a slow and string-only localstorage item instead of a local integer variable? You can still store that value in localstorage after the loop.

Comment: You reset the value to `0` on every iteration of the loop. Do the initialisation only once, before the loop.

Comment: Yup, don't use localStorage (or just put the result in there after the loop.)
 Also don't assume all days are exactly 86400000 long.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is thers is always reinitialization - `localStorage.setItem("dayscost0", "0")`on each iteration. Try moving it outside of the for-loop.

```js
localStorage.setItem("dayscost0", "0") //setting day count in each range to zero in local storage
for (let i = 0; i < daysDifference; i++) {  //for loop to go through each day
    let dayDot = startTime + (i * 86400000); // getting the range for each day of the booking in millisecs
    if (dayDot <= 1639746000000 && dayDot >= 1634648400000) { // setting range for price blocks
      let cost = (parseInt(localStorage.getItem('dayscost0')) + 1); //incrementing by one each time a value fits the range
      localStorage.setItem("dayscost0", cost.toString()) //adding the value to local storage
      console.log('dayscost0') 
    }
}
```